# jquery ajax compatibility in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var searchValue = "";
    setInterval(checkTextboxChanged, 0.5);
    function checkTextboxChanged() {
        var currentValue = $('#dept').val();
        if (currentValue != searchValue) {
            searchValue = currentValue;
            TextboxChanged();
        }
    }
    function TextboxChanged() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_price.html",
        data: "dept="+$("#dept").val()+"&arrive="+$("#arrive").val()+"&parking="+$("#parking").val(),
        success: function(result){ 
          $("#check_price").html(result);
        }
      }); 
    }

});
```

This is working fine in Chrome,firefox but not in IE.. is it any problem in setInterval method? is it supports IE?

Comment: maybe 0.5 milliseconds is not an acceptable value in IE, it demands an int

Comment: Yes, ie supports setInterval. this code is bad, instead of using a .5ms interval you should be using the change event or a similar event. I don't see anything specific in your code that would choke in IE.

Comment: @davidkonrad  Your assumption is right. I just change 0.5ms to 1 and it works fine. thank you very much sir..

Comment: Besides the wrong approach [polling over events], checking 2k times per second for a keystroke would still be overkill!

Comment: agreed with @moonwave99 -- I suspect you actually intended 0.5 seconds rather than 0.5 milliseconds? If so, the value you should specify is `500`, not `0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` with a small timeout is a really *really* bad idea, whichever browser you're using.

The thing with `setInterval` is that the event is triggered on the specified interval regardless of whether the page is ready for it.

With a short interval time, this can very easily lead to a pile-up of events that are fired faster than the site can deal with them.

Your usage here, with ajax involved is a classic example of this: If the ajax event takes longer than half a second to complete (which is easily possible), then you'll end up with multiple events being called virtually simulataneously. This will lead to your ajax service being swamped with simultaneous calls, which will make its response time slow down, and in turn make the problem in the browser even worse.

With this kind of thing, it is almost always better to use a self re-firing `setTimeout` call, which will ensure that the event is never triggered until the previous one has completed.

However, either way, your interval of 0.5ms is a crazy short time span for any kind of interval handling. You will very likely have performance issues with a timeout that short, whatever it is you're doing.

I suspect that you actually intended it to be half a second rather than half a millisecond. If that's the case, you should change it to `500` rather than `0.5`.